# MySql поиск по телефону

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с пользователями и есть ячейка с номером телефона. Все телефоны записаны в формате: 8 (999) 999-99-99

Как сделать запрос так что бы пользователь мог вводить такие форматы для поиска:
999-99-99 или 9999999...

Comment: В базе данные надо хранить без форматирования и разделителей и форматировать только при выводе. тогда и поиск будет тривиальным

Comment: А так у вас единственный путь отформатировать данные для запроса в так же как они выглядят в базе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f7c1/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table tel (
  tel nvarchar(32)
);

insert into tel(tel) values (N'8 (999) 999-99-99');
insert into tel(tel) values (N'8 (123) 123-12-13');
insert into tel(tel) values (N'8 (444) 444-12-99');
insert into tel(tel) values (N'8 (456) 888-89-98');
insert into tel(tel) values (N'8 (000) 009-09-09');
insert into tel(tel) values (N'8 (009) 909-09-09');
```

**Query**:

```
select tel from tel where INSTR(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(tel,N' ',N''),N'-',N''),N'(',N''),N')',N''), N'99')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f7c1/2/0)**:

```
|               tel |
|-------------------|
| 8 (999) 999-99-99 |
| 8 (444) 444-12-99 |
| 8 (456) 888-89-98 |
| 8 (009) 909-09-09 |
```

Жуть, конечно, но что-то лучше не гуглится. А вообще, лучше не держать форматированные данные в базе, тем более, если формат всегда один и тот же.